# Implement HEAD and TITLE tags with DB DATA

Tags: templates

I need to customize HEAD and TITLE of a page with data taken from database.

How can I do that?

Can you provide me some guidelines and best practices?

Answer (score 0):

What data are you looking to put in the tags?

I'm just trying to understand if it's data that Wordpress may already make available.

This seems to be the right way to get to data in the Wordpress database: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Once you have the data, you can use wp_head to get the values in the HEAD section. Check out: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head

For the TITLE, you may need to edit the templates.

Comment: I have a wordpress page that receive parameters by url rewriting...
In this page a use a plugin to execute php code that access the database...
I works properly but now I have to customize the page headers in order to make it SEO Friendly.
The page is just a container used to load 1000+ products details...
Thanks

Comment: Okay, so you have something like http://www.example.com/product.php?var=12 and you want to use 12 to query the database? - In this case, I'm sure you'd want to use wpdb to query the database with that value. And to get the variable from the URL, check this out: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Comment: I'm already able to pass parameters by url Rewriting and it works properly.
In the page content I access a db and I can print the data but now, I have to use db data to manage page header and I don't know how to doit...
May be I have to work with "the_title" or some function like that...